# Partition of harddisk lost/unusable

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition, core-storage

I'm using OS X Yosemite - version 10.10.2. I have 1.12 TB fusion drive on my system. Recently I wanted to make a partition on my system, while making the partition on the system using disk utility some error occurred and partition was not created successfully.

The unusable partition of the disk.

[image: The unusable partition]

The partition is not available here either.
[image: diskutil list]

[image: diskutil corestorage list]

So, here I'm not able to access the free space partition of my disk.
The disk utility is not working with the free space partition. I want to resize the partition and want to have only single partition disk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to boot from another device or to Internet Recovery Mode and then use the command line to modify the CoreStorage volume.

**Preparation:**

- Backup your data.
- Detach any external drive (especially your external Time Machine backup drive).
- Restart to Internet Recovery Mode by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> at startup.
  The prerequisites are the latest firmware update installed, either ethernet or WLAN (WPA/WPA2) and a router with DHCP activated.
  On a 50 Mbps-line it takes about 4 min (presenting a small animated globe) to boot to a recovery netboot image which usually is loaded from an apple/akamai server.

  I recommend ethernet because it's more reliable. If you are restricted to WIFI and the boot process fails, just restart your Mac until you succeed booting.

  Alternatively you may start from a bootable installer thumb drive (Mavericks or Yosemite) or a thumb drive containing a full system (Mavericks or Yosemite).

**Modify CoreStorage:**

- Open in the menubar Utilities/Terminal
- Enter `diskutil cs list`
- Enter `diskutil cs resizeStack LVUUID size` with LVUUID: UUID of the logical volume and size: the final size of your Macintosh HD
  Example:
  `diskutil cs resizeStack C6AE5E40-1B4F-4AED-BD80-9E71EB6F1352 1000g`
  to expand it to 1.0 TB
  `diskutil cs resizeStack C6AE5E40-1B4F-4AED-BD80-9E71EB6F1352 0g` or
  `diskutil cs resizeStack C6AE5E40-1B4F-4AED-BD80-9E71EB6F1352 100%`
  to expand it to the full size with magic numbers.
- Enter `exit` and quit Terminal.
- Reboot to your main volume.